# Replacing Type with var for all 'Class class = new Class()' usages in Java project

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I recently switched to Java 11 for a rather big project, and would like to switch to using `var class = new Class()` instead of `Class class = new CLass()`.

I tried using Intellij Structural Search (and replace) for this, but its turning out to be more complex than expected.

My first attempt was `$Type$ $Inst$ = new $Constructor$($Argument$);`, which also matches global variables (which don't allow var).

My second attempt is:

```
class $Class$ {
  $ReturnType$ $Method$ ($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws $ExceptionType$ {
      $Statements$;
      final $Type$ $Inst$ = new $Constructor$($Argument$);
      $Statements2$;
  }
}
```

Which misses all calls inside e.g. try blocks (since they get matched by the expressions)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first template

```
$Type$ $Inst$ = new $Constructor$($Argument$);
```

But add a `Script` modifier on the `$Inst$` variable with the following text:
`Inst instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiLocalVariable`

Alternatively you may want to try the *Local variable type can be omitted* inspection that is available in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Extra info: Apply the script to the `Inst` field. And ensure 'Injected code` is enabled in your structural search & replace window.

Comment: I have modified my answer to include the info that the script should be added to the $Inst$ variable. Enabling 'Injected code' should not be necessary for regular Java code.

Comment: injected code has to be enabled, or the script cannot resolve `Inst`, and the com.intellij.psi package won't be available. (at least this was the case for me)